# Cheapest fare from Gatwick airport to Greenwich

Tags: transit, trains, budget, london

Next week I am flying to Gatwick airport in London, and then I must go to Abbey Wood train station (in Greenwich) which is where I am staying. I believe the easiest route is to use trains, connecting at London Bridge, but I am a bit confused with the fares. What would be the cheapest fare for this route? I am not planning to use an Oyster card for my stay as for the next 7 days I will use a Zones 1-4 Travel Card, but I also wouldn't like to burn one of my travel card days for this journey (I will arrive late at night, so I don't see a point of getting one day less on my travel card for a single journey). Is there an option to buy a ticket for this route only (so no 1 day ticket) without having an Oyster card? Or what would be the cheapest option for me?

Comment: I think your best bet is probably actually an oyster card, you get travelcrad prices there too.

Comment: Do you have a contactless bank card? You can use that as/instead of an Oystercard and get Oystercard prices on it.

Comment: I do not have a contactless bank card, unfortunately. If I would buy an Oyster card at the airport and use it only for this route (and probably also for the reverse route when I fly back home) how much would the connection cost me?

Comment: Buying a train ticket would be £17.40 for an off-peak single, or £30.50 for an off-peak return. Oyster or contactless is noticeably cheaper, at £8 each way (again, off peak), so may be cheapest even if you factor in the cost of the Oyster card. Note that you can't use a Z1-4 travel card to get to/from Gatwick, it's considerably further out than that.

Comment: Buy an Oyster card before you go to the UK.

Comment: @MichaelHampton What is the advantage of buying it before instead of buying it at the airport?

Comment: The advantage is that you'll have it when you arrive at Gatwick. You said you arrive late at night, but the Visitor Centre in Gatwick (which sells Oyster cards) closes at 16:00, and [there aren't currently any other authorised Oyster ticket vendors](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/74747/3221) there. You will be able to buy a rail ticket, of course, but as @djr noted, it would cost more without an Oyster card.

Comment: @MichaelHampton This is great advice, thank you so much, I wasn't aware the centre closed at 16 o'clock. I will take a look and see if I can get an Oyster card delivery to Germany within the next 6 days.

Comment: See https://tfl.gov.uk/fares-and-payments/where-to-top-up-and-buy-tickets/overseas-travel-agents for a list of places where you can buy Oyster cards outside the UK.

Comment: You can put the travelcard on the Oyster too, you know?

Comment: According to [this](http://www.visitlondon.com/traveller-information/travel-to-london/airport/gatwick#Kzv1hjwbjWGVPjP1.97) website, you can buy an Oyster card in Gatwick at three different places: "[...] at the Concierge outlets in Gatwick North Terminal or Gatwick South Terminal. [...] You can also buy an Oyster Card at the Skybreak Service Centre in both terminals and at the Gatwick Airport train station." If that is correct, then I suppose the closing times wouldn't be a problem since the cashiers at the train station is opened until later than 4pm

Comment: @MichaelHampton: According to http://www.nationalrail.co.uk/stations_destinations/GTW.aspx, the ticket office at Gatwick Airport railway station is open 24/7 and does sell Oyster cards. There are probably also self-service Oyster vending machines.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Hm. That's new. And good to know.

Comment: I love these sorts of questions. Even though I'm a Londoner I often learn something useful.

Comment: @TheMathemagician Thanks :) And by the way, a small follow up since I am already in London. Indeed one can buy an Oyster card at Gatwick, but it works as follows: you can only buy a regular Oyster card on North Terminal. In the train station in the South Terminal, they could only sell us a Visitor Oyster card. The drawbacks are 1) the fixed £3 non-refundable fee for the card, 2) fixed initial £30 top up and the other points raised by others above.

Comment: Also, when comparing journey fares between a single ticket, Oyster card and Travel Card, one must remember that buses are charged £1.50 extra with Oyster card if you leave the Tube + rail system, while a single fare or Travel card are valid according to zones and therefore include buses. If your daily journey involves a bus + train/metro, it might really be cheaper to get a Travel card instead of an Oyster.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best solution pricewise would be buying an Oyster card or getting a contactless bank card if those are cheaper to get at your bank.
You may need to buy the Oyster card before arriving in London, you certainly will need to if you want to use a Visitor Oyster card.

With an Oyster card your journey will cost you £8, (off peak,) a one way train ticket (also off peak) is £17.40.

The cost of a Visitor Oyster Card is £3 more than the credit on it, [as you can see on this site.](https://tfl.gov.uk/travel-information/visiting-london/visitor-oyster-card) So even for a single journey you are better off using that card.
You can get any remaining credit paid out when you use a ticket machine at the end of your stay, if the stay is more than 3 days. The card will remain yours but without value. If you plan to return in the near future, or have friends who plan a London visit, you can also leave the credit on and use the card at a later date.
Credit remains valid, no end date.

If you have a contact less bank card, the same prices for travel apply, without the need to have an extra card.

All prices taken from the comments on the question, except where I put in a link.

Comment: If you're going to get a 7-day travelcard anyway, consider having it issued on the Oyster instead of a separate paper ticket. The price is the same, but the Oyster system will automatically switch between using the travelcard or PAYG credits depending on whether you're traveling within the travelcard's validity area. In particular, if the travelcard is still valid when you're going back to Gatwick, you would only need to pay extra for the part of that trip that's outside Z1234.

Comment: Can you put a 7 day travelcard on a visitor Oystercard?

Comment: x @Willeke: No, Vistor Oyster cannot contain travelcards, period. (It seems to be a strictly inferior product in most other respects than being available via mail order).

Comment: One more reason to get a suitable bank card, but that might take too long.

Comment: Bank cards can't have a travelcard either.

Comment: You can not put a travel card on it, but the contactless bank card has a monday to sunday capping build in, https://tfl.gov.uk/fares-and-payments/contactless/what-is-capping?intcmp=20487